# Weird result comparing property values using reflection

Tags: comparison, properties

Can someone explain why this is occurring?  The code below was executed in the immediate window in vs2008.  The prop is an Int32 property (id column) on an object created by the entity framework.

The objects entity and defaultEntity were created using Activator.CreateInstance();

Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(entity, null), prop.PropertyType)
0
Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(defaultEntity, null), prop.PropertyType)
0
Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(entity, null), prop.PropertyType) == Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(defaultEntity, null), prop.PropertyType)
false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're wondering why the third line prints false. If you want to know why the first two lines are printing 0, you'll have to post more code and tell us what you actually expected.

`Convert.ChangeType` returns `object`. Therefore when the property type is actually `Int32` it will return a *boxed* integer.

Your final line is comparing the *references* of two boxed values. Effectively you're doing:

```
object x = 0;
object y = 0;
Console.WriteLine (x == y); // Prints False
```

You can use `Equals` instead - and the static `object.Equals` method handily copes with null references, should that be an issue:

```
object x = 0;
object y = 0;
Console.WriteLine (object.Equals(x, y)); // Prints True
```

Comment: Yep, I ended up figuring that out with some help from a co-worker.  .Equals gets me what I want.

Is there a way to check if that object is a string or integer without explicitly checking each condition?

Comment: What do you mean by "checking each condition"? You can either use "is" or call GetType().